# How to replace NULL in SQL OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, replace, null

In this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0665/36/0) I am trying to replace CompanyName to something else if it is null but apparently I cannot. I tried case statement and other techniques but it did not work. Is there away to replace CompanyName lets say by 'Not Given' if the company is null.

I must use OUTER APPLY here.

Comment: Not sure why you must use `outer apply`, your query can be done using a simple `[left] join`.

Comment: My original query is more complex uses subquery with top record selected only. This is just a repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select p.*, isnull(czip.companyname, 'Not Given') companyname
from Person p
outer apply (
    select  companyname 
    from Company c
    where p.companyid = c.companyId
) Czip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Coalesce(companyname, 'Not Given') As companyname
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try out isnull

```
SELECT IsNull(companyname, 'Comp not present') As companyname
```

check this : [SQL ISNULL(), NVL(), IFNULL() and COALESCE() Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)